# How to setup jms in Red Hat middleware to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, redhat, middleware

I run Red Hat middleware with CodeReady Studio 12.16.0.GA on standalone Spring-boot environment as local Camel context. I have local RabbitMQ running in Docker.
I have failed to setup any scenario using tutorials on web in/out JMS using Camel.
All tutorials don't use camel-context.xml configuration only pure java spring.
Please help me to configure camel-context.xml and all resource to use RabbitMQ or just any JMS.

Thanks in advance.

Here is simple camel-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring       https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="simple-route">
            <from id="_to1" uri="jms:myQeue?connectionFactory=#myConnectionFactory&amp;jmsMessageType=Text"/>
            <log id="route-log" message=">>> ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

and simple spring application to run it

```
package org.mycompany;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/camel-context.xml"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But it went to exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: jms://myQeue?connectionFactory=%23myConnectionFactory&jmsMessageType=Text due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: myConnectionFactory of type: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
```

I have added registration of ConnectionFactory

```
    ConnectionFactory myCF = new ConnectionFactory();
    myCF.setUsername("guest");
    myCF.setPassword("guest");
    myCF.setVirtualHost("/");
    myCF.setHost("localhost");
    myCF.setPort(5672);
    SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry(); 
    reg.put("myConnectionFactory", myCF);
    CamelContext camContext = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);
```

but new exception arose I think because of using com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route simple-route: Route(simple-route)[[From[jms:queue:myQeue?connectionFactory... because of connectionFactory must be specified
```

How to define javax.jms.ConnectionFactory to registry?

Comment: Can you add here what you have set up and tried?

Comment: A have tried many examples. At the end I used this https://www.javainuse.com/camel/camel_rabbit but this example doesn't use camel-contest.xml.